# JasperReports: got empty Details band when compiling .jrxml to .jasper files

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a well working program, which uses *JasperReports*. It uses `JRBeanCollectionDataSource(List items)` to populate the rows with data, but if I compile the *jrxml* file either with `JasperCompileManager.compileToFile()` or with *iReport* I see only parameters populated without rows.

Does anyone have had such a problem? I don't receive any errors or exceptions.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Without seeing source from your jrxml template it's hard to say anything meaningful. On the other side it wouldn't be wise to expose details of your work in public. You should try to narrow the question. If your app already uses JasperReports take some time to study how do they work, read some tutorial and ask for help when you'll be having something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. 
My jasperreports.jar and the program's jasperreports.jar were different versions. So when I compile the reports with my jar and run it with the older, even without making changes of the jrxml, the rows didn't appear.

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You should accept your own answer so it is clear that the question is resolved. That will increase your standing in the community, because it will not be so annoying for people who come and want to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile the report using IReport or JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(), you say that you don't see rows.

You don't give enough details about :

- The version of IReport(ie. of
  JasperReports in IReport) vs the
  version of JasperReports that you use
  in production. Old versions of JasperReports use a DTD whereas the new version uses an XML schema.
- Are you passing a bean collection in
  IReport so that it can populate rows?

Usually people compile JasperReports at build time, in production, you always refer to the compile version.

The only reason you would compile a report at runtime is if you're trying to generate a report yourself from a form, dynamically. If that's the case, double-check the syntax of the file that you're generating.